# Adding pages to IIS Website

Tags: iis

Right now I'm using IIS 8.5 to host a few applications (web pages) on the Default Web Site.

I add the page as an application, give it an Alias(test) and point it at the folder that holds my web page.

I can reach this page by typing `http://gisedn/test` in  my browser, both from the server itself and from my desktop(at work), but not externally(at home).

I add a new Website called 'Fred' and the add an application 'Dave'.

If I type `http://gisedn/Dave` (at work) I get a 404 - not found error.

I think it probably has something to do with the bindings and port 80.

Is it possible to setup multiple web sites on a single IP address/server?

What fundamental error am I making? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are not using routable domain names. You are using NetBios names which are only routable on Microsoft networks. The Internet does not know what *gisedn* is. For you to access your website external to work, you need a domain name (example.com), a static IP address or a way of using dynamic DNS (DDNS), the ability to route these requests through the firewall, and so on. You will need to talk to your network administrator to set this up. But one warning. They may not allow it for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can set up multiple websites under a single IP address in IIS, see [Host Headers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx).

Like closetnoc said, you also need to register your domain as a .com or something and point it to your web server's IP address - "gisedn" is not a public address so you won't be able to access it outside the local network where you've deployed it.

Alternatively, you could connect to that network remotely with a VPN and that would give you access to the URL in question. Or you can try accessing the site from the server's public IP address. Go to http://whatismyipaddress.com/ from the server. Once you have the server's IP, you could try replacing "gisedn" with the IP to see if that lets you access the website from a remote network. If the server, network, or ISP is blocking HTTP (port 80) traffic or otherwise misconfigured then you won't get through.